# ScriptableSingleton Unity return 0 values

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using ScriptableSingleton to store my PlayerAbilities as shown below in the picture.

But in the code I am getting the values as 0.

 For eg, below is the ScriptableSingleton Created :

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "PlayerStatsFileName", menuName = "PlayerScriptableObject/PlayerAbilities")]
public class PlayerAbilities : ScriptableSingleton<PlayerAbilities>
{
    [Header("Abilities")] 
    [SerializeField] private int _movementSpeed;
    
    public float GetRunningSpeed()
    {
        return _movementSpeed;
    }
}
```

And when called in the code:

```
Debug.Log("PlayerAbilities :" + PlayerAbilities.instance.GetRunningSpeed());
```

This is always returning 0 even though when values are specified as below.

[image]

So, I tried building it to see if it is due to the editor but on building we have this error:

[image]

i.e :

```
The type or namespace name 'ScriptableSingleton<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can this be solved, what am I missing?

Comment: Could you please add ScriptableSingleton code and its place in project hierarchy ?

Comment: Apologies, i couldnt get it. Were you asking for the code, it was the above btw..and i was calling it directly as  ```PlayerAbilities.instance.GetRunningSpeed()``` from a different code. And one more thing ScriptableSingleton seems to be in Editor namespace.

Comment: As you said, its editor code so you cannot use it for your game. You could easily create your own version of it though using a singleton implementation that inherits from ScriptableObject

Comment: Apologies, didn't know that it's part of UnityEditor namespace. I thought you developed your own singleton.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptableSingleton is in UnityEditor namespace. We need to create our own implementation that inherits from ScriptableObject.